# Confusion about SELECT DISTINCT in SQL

Tags: sql, select, distinct

When I select COLUMN_1 only I get the right amount of 8 rows in my database because it doesn't give me duplicate rows and its what I want

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_3=12;
```

but when select both COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 it gives me 53 rows in my database and that's not what I want...

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_3=12;
```

I know when I select two columns with `distinct`, it will give me unique values for the combination of the two columns. `DISTINCT` is applied to the combination of the columns, not just the first column. So my question is how do I select both `COLUMN_1` and `COLUMN_2` so that they give me 8 rows and no duplicates ???? because as soon as I add `COLUMN_2` it gives more rows that I am supposed to have..

Comment: If Column2 is numeric, you can either take min , max or avg of the values and then group by Column_1, if Column_2 is not numeric, then you have to decide the values you want to select and use it in the where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to decide *which* value for `column_2` you want.

One simple way is a `group by`:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1, min(COLUMN_2)
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_3=12
GROUP BY COLUMN_1;
```

Comment: You have to choose MIN, MAX, AVG, etc. depending on what you're looking for.  If you want the last record you'd use this as an inner query and join it back to the table so you can select TOP 1 based on a defined sort.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not think of MIN

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on your exact requirements but a nice solution here could be to use some king of aggregation function that prevents the duplication but still returns all of the values from the column causing the duplication e.g.

The following data,

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
-----------------
a       | x
b       | x
c       | y
a       | z
b       | y
a       | y
```

Would be displayed as,

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
-----------------
a       | x,z,y
b       | x,y
c       | y
```

You don't specify the database you are using but in Oracle you could use the [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) function which could be something like the following in your case:

```
SELECT COLUMN1,
       LISTAGG(COLUMN2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN2) "COLUMN2_VALUES",
  FROM TABLE
```

If you're not using Oracle, and this sounds like a suitable solution, then it's worth checking if you RDBMS of choice provides something similar.