# SQL Select Distinct ONLY giving me header of another table not distinct rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

I am trying to select only the distinct rows for a query in PostgreSQL.

I have the following code:

```
 INSERT INTO Products
 ("Unique ID","Manufacturer Name","Manufacturer Part Number","Packaging UOM")
 SELECT 
  'Unique ID',
  'Manufacturer Name',
  'Manufacturer Part Number',
  'Packaging UOM'
 FROM 
  All_Catalogs
```

When I replace Select with Select Distinct I end up only heading the header of the table All_Catalogs instead of all of the values.

I don't want to select all and the drop the duplicates of Unique ID, I'd rather initially only grab the rows with unique 'Unique IDs'

I appreciate any help/advice.

When trying to look online:
[Confusion about SELECT DISTINCT in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792815/confusion-about-select-distinct-in-sql)
-This suggested Group By which I got 'non-int errors' so it wouldn't work for me
[SELECT DISTINCT values and INSERT INTO table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014183/select-distinct-values-and-insert-into-table)
-This again suggested group by which I got non-int error

Comment: Distinct is selection of only one row for any duplicate rows (select columns list). Distinct is not combining...

Answer (score 0):

This query will only select rows with `UniqueID` unique to `All_Catalogs`

```
 INSERT INTO Products
 ("Unique ID","Manufacturer Name","Manufacturer Part Number","Packaging UOM")
 SELECT 
  "Unique ID",
  "Manufacturer Name",
  "Manufacturer Part Number",
  "Packaging UOM"
 FROM 
  All_Catalogs
 WHERE "Unique ID" IN (SELECT "Unique ID" 
    FROM All_Catalogs 
    GROUP BY "Unique ID" 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am still getting the error that 'Unique ID' in a non-int for the Group By...I am trying to figure out why this is.

Comment: both datatypes are text

Comment: @Alexis, you are using 'Unique ID' which is a string literal, can use "Unique ID" in Select and group by as mentioned by FuzzyTree, this should work. In case of duplicates, do you want to retain one row? in that case above query requires a change.